# What happens to my AppStore rating when updating my App?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, rating

My app now has reached 5 ratings and is shown in the AppStore list with 5 stars now.

I sent an update to Apple which I marked "Hold for developer release".

Now:

**(a)** If I released the update, what would happen to my ratings? Are the people who rated for Version 1.0 allowed to rate again for Version 1.0.1?

**(b)** If (a) is true, are they allowed just to "rate" or to "rate and write a review" again?

**(c)** If nobody rates again, are the 5 stars still be shown?

**(d)** If (c) is true, no ratings are displayed in the AppStore list?

Comment: Perfect question for our [App Store StackExchange Site Proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores?referrer=jcBbxTFsYbhSPTdluUKgFA2) Click and commit to make that site happen. Otherwise the offtopic-voters will haunt you. ;-P

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about programming, better to ask apple directly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(a) People are allowed to rate again (in the fact, you can always rate again app, but only last rate is stored)
(b) They are allowed to rate and write a review
(c) Your rating will split to two ratings "current version" and "all versions", older, not updated, ratings will be available in "all versions" section.

-- updated 
(d) When application has less than 5 ratings for current version, on app page is shown only average rating for "all versions"

Comment: Thanks so far, please look at (d)!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know which list you have in mind

Comment: E.g. if I enter my company name in the search field.

Comment: If you mean windows which appears after click on "i" button, this presents "current version" rating if it's available, and "all versions" if not.